# What is the correct way of handling JSON RecordID?

Tags: json, orientjs

I have a piece of JSON that printed to console looks like:

```
{ '@rid': RecordID { cluster: 45, position: 40 } }
```

Stringifying this returns:

```
{"@rid":"#45:40"}
```

However, I'd prefer if the RecordID was not converted to a string.

I can pick out the individual values by:

```
json["@rid"].cluster   // returns 45
json["@rid"].position  // returns 40
```

But handling the RecordID directly always returns an error. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

This is half an answer but there's a parse method:

```
const RID = require('orientjs').RecordID;
RID.parse(result['@rid'])
```

Is returns a record, but not the string that would be, you know, useful.